# Name for first line of something

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, names

Is there a term for the first line of something, whether it's a poem, song, or prose?

Addendum: Sometimes, though not always, the first line is the same as the title, such as in Walt Whitman’s poem “[I Sing the Body Electric](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/174740)”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Incipit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incipit):

> - The opening words of a text, especially when used in place of a title to identify an otherwise untitled work. (AHD)

Comment: Wow, nice word. Not heard that one before.

Comment: “The word ‘incipit’ comes from Latin and means ‘it begins’.”

Nice etymology!